# Error in mocking non-virtual function using GTest/GMock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am using GTest to write UT for my code.

In order to test "non-virtual" functions, i generated the "function mangled name" using "nm" utility and added it in the "test suite.cpp" file (under extern "C") in the below format

__wrap_Mangled_name (function args as in original)

and then linked the same in "tst_def" file. Still when i run the test suite, the original function in the source code gets called instead of this "wrapped one". But in fact, this wrapped function should be called .

I cross-checked whether this mangled name is correct or not using "C++filt" utility and it was correct.

Any suggestions for this?

Thanks,

Udhai

Comment: may be don't link the cpp file with original implementation when you build the unit test executable?

Comment: As u say, when I comment out the actual function implementation, my wrapped function is getting called..but still when i wrap and link this function in my test suite, I guess the expected behaviour is to call the wrapped one?